# Pinching to zoom in and out of table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nstableview, pinch, pinchzoom

As is done in the ["Clear" to-do management app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ksizx2-nEmk), is the pinching to navigate back from a table view achievable using reasonably standard interface elements, or is this a lot of manual coding hackery?

Answer (score 2):

It's not! http://simplecodebits.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/pinch-zoom-uitableview.html